# numpy '==' switches semantics as operands grow in size

Tags: python, numpy, operators, equals, array-broadcasting

Just stumbled over the following:

```
Python 3.6.0 (default, Jan  9 2017, 22:01:27) 
[GCC 4.8.5] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> np.version.version
'1.14.2'
>>> 
>>> a = np.ones((100,), np.uint8)
>>> (a[:, None] == a).shape
(100, 100)
>>> a = np.ones((10000,), np.uint8)
>>> (a[:, None] == a).shape
(10000, 10000)
```

So far so expected, but now:

```
>>> a = np.ones((1000000,), np.uint8)
>>> (a[:, None] == a).shape
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

In fact:

```
>>> a[:, None] == a
False
```

Can anyone reproduce this?
Is it a bug or some kind of feature? If a feature is it documented somewhere?

Other operators just raise a memory error

```
>>> a[:, None] | a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

which makes much more sense in my opinion.

Comment: How long does `a[:, None] == a` take to compute in the last scenario? On my system, running this crashed my interpreter. (version '1.14.0' btw, so this is likely a bug)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It returns instantly. Ok, timed it: around 10 us

Comment: Definitely a bug, cannot reproduce on 1.14.0. You should file a bug report...

Comment: I can reproduce it with the very same setup, the comparison returns `False` instantly. `np.equal` raises `MemoryError`. This answer may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35397876/5629339

Comment: @filippo Geez, googling is really not my strongest suit. Thanks, that's very likely it.

Comment: From the link by @filippo it seems like this is known behavior that's deprecated since 1.9, but still hasn't actually been removed yet by 1.14? So presumably the answer is to not depend on either behavior until some point even farther in the future… It's obviously not that easy to do that without knowing in advance what might cause a `MemoryError`, except by `np.equal` whenever there's any chance at all of one?