# Comparing numpy array of dtype object

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

My question is "why?:"

```
aa[0]
array([[405, 162, 414, 0,
        array([list([1, 9, 2]), 18, (405, 18, 207), 64, 'Universal'],
      dtype=object),
        0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)

aaa
array([[405, 162, 414, 0,
        array([list([1, 9, 2]), 18, (405, 18, 207), 64, 'Universal'],
      dtype=object),
        0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)

np.array_equal(aaa,aa[0])
False
```

Those arrays are completly identical.

My minimal example doesn't reproduce this:

```
be=np.array([1],dtype=object)

be
array([1], dtype=object)

ce=np.array([1],dtype=object)

ce
array([1], dtype=object)

np.array_equal(be,ce)
True
```

Nor does this one:

```
ce=np.array([np.array([1]),'5'],dtype=object)

be=np.array([np.array([1]),'5'],dtype=object)

np.array_equal(be,ce)
True
```

### However, to reproduce my problem try this:

```
be=np.array([[405, 162, 414, 0, np.array([list([1, 9, 2]), 18, (405, 18, 207), 64, 'Universal'],dtype=object),0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)

ce=np.array([[405, 162, 414, 0, np.array([list([1, 9, 2]), 18, (405, 18, 207), 64, 'Universal'],dtype=object),0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)

np.array_equal(be,ce)
False

np.array_equal(be[0],ce[0])
False
```

And I have no idea why those are not equal. And to add the bonus question, **how do I compare them?**

**I need an efficient way to check if aaa is in the stack aa.**

*I'm not using `aaa in aa` because of `DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.` and because it still returns `False` if anyone is wondering.*

---

### What else have I tried?:

```
np.equal(be,ce)
*** ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

np.all(be,ce)
*** TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

all(be,ce)
*** TypeError: all() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

all(be==ce)
*** TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

np.where(be==ce)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

And these, which I can't get to run in the console, all evaluate to False, some giving the deprecation warning:

```
import numpy as np

ce=np.array([[405, 162, 414, 0, np.array([list([1, 9, 2]), 18, (405, 18, 207), 64, 'Universal'],dtype=object),0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)

be=np.array([[405, 162, 414, 0, np.array([list([1, 9, 2]), 18, (405, 18, 207), 64, 'Universal'],dtype=object),0, 0, 0]], dtype=object)

print(np.any([bee in ce for bee in be]))

print(np.any([bee==cee for bee in be for cee in ce]))

print(np.all([bee in ce for bee in be]))

print(np.all([bee==cee for bee in be for cee in ce]))
```

And of course [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10580676/7322095) telling me this should work...

Comment: Btw: I'm doing this in a recursive function to limit the recursions, so if someone knows how to do this efficiently, maybe even stopping the comparisons when one evaluates True, maybe sth. like *[break if x == aaa for x in aa]* if that's possible. I'd be forever grateful! ;-)

Comment: As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426587/what-is-going-on-behind-this-numpy-selection-behavior) by @user2357112, *"NumPy is designed for rigid multidimensional grids of numbers. Trying to get anything but a rigid multidimensional grid is going to be painful."* or @juanpa.arrivillaga: "Moral of the story: Don't use `dtype=object` arrays. They are stunted Python lists, with worse performance characteristics, and numpy is not designed to handle the case of sequence-like containers within these object arrays."

Comment: @Kanak if I need to do aa[:,0:3]/np.array([1,9,2]) a list makes those operations hellish. I'm totally fine with another container if you have any suggestion? I don't want to split the informations though, my code i unreadable enough without drawing data that belongs together from x places.

Comment: Doing calculations with object dtype array is hit-or-miss.  Some things work fine (though not as fast as with numeric dtypes), other things don't.  A lot has to do with whether object elements implement the necessary methods.

Comment: @hpaulj what would be a better way? I'm open to any suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make an element-wise comparison between the arrays, you can use [**`numpy.equal()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html) with the keyword argument `dtype=numpy.object` as in :

```
In [60]: np.equal(be, ce, dtype=np.object)
Out[60]: 
array([[True, True, True, True,
        array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]), True, True, True]],
      dtype=object)
```

**P.S.** checked using NumPy version `1.15.2`  and Python `3.6.6`

### edit

From the release notes for 1.15,

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/release.html#comparison-ufuncs-accept-dtype-object-overriding-the-default-bool

```
Comparison ufuncs accept dtype=object, overriding the default bool

This allows object arrays of symbolic types, which override == and 
other operators to return expressions, to be compared elementwise with 
np.equal(a, b, dtype=object).
```

Comment: I tried your code and it gives me "No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc equal" error. Perhaps something wrong with dtype?

Comment: I'm getting the same error. (now that I moved this out of a misplaced try: statement)

Comment: Maybe a python 2 / 3 thing?

Comment: It could be a version thing.  It works for me with 3.6 and 1.15.1.

Comment: @hpaulj it doesn't work for me with python 3.6 and numpy 1.14.5+

Comment: I can confirm, **upgrading numpy solves the issue**. only change: upgrading numpy from 1.14.5 to 1.15.2 and now it evaluates to True. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To complement @kmario23's answer, what about doing

```
def wrpr(bools):
    try:
      # ints  = bools.flatten().prod()
        fltn_bools = np.hstack(bools)
    except: # should not pass silently.
        fltn_bools = np.array(wrpr(a) for a in bools)        
    ints = fltn_bools.prod()
    if isinstance(ints, np.ndarray):
        return wrpr(ints)
    return bool(ints)
```

And finally,

```
>>> wrpr(np.equal(ce, be, dtype=np.object))
True
```

Checked *using (numpy1.15.1 & Python 3.6.5) & (numpy1.15.1 & Python 2.7.13).*

---

But still, as commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426587/what-is-going-on-behind-this-numpy-selection-behavior)

> NumPy is designed for rigid multidimensional grids of numbers. Trying to get anything but a rigid multidimensional grid is going to be painful. *(@user2357112, Jul 31 '17 at 23:10)*

and/or

> Moral of the story: Don't use `dtype=object` arrays. They are stunted Python lists, with worse performance characteristics, and numpy is not designed to handle the case of sequence-like containers within these object arrays.
>   *(@juanpa.arrivillaga, Jul 31 '17 at 23:38)*

Comment: "TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc equal"

Comment: @DonQuiKong What does `np.__version__` return?

Comment: I just tried it and upgrading numpy resolves the issue. (from 1.14.5 to 1.15.2)

Comment: What about `wrpr(np.array([np.array([True, True]), np.array([True, True, True])]))` ? I am getting _ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)_

Comment: Indeed @HlibBabii. See the new `wrpr`'s definition, which may suit you, while still doing the same job as before.

Comment: @keepAlive this still won't work for `np.array([np.array([[True, True]]), np.array([True, True, True])]`. Indeed painful :)

Comment: @HlibBabii The last version of `wrpr` works. ***Tested*** with your two examples.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you are seeing is kind of documented [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160220091630/https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/release.html#id15)

> Deprecations¶
>
> ...
>
> Object array equality comparisons
>
> In the future object array comparisons both == and np.equal will not
>   make use of identity checks anymore. For example:
>
> > > >
> > >
> > > > a = np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), 1])
> > > >
> > > > b = np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), 1])
> > > >
> > > > a == b
>
> will consistently return False (and in the future an error) even if
>   the array in a and b was the same object.
>
> The equality operator == will in the future raise errors like np.equal
>   if broadcasting or element comparisons, etc. fails.
>
> Comparison with arr == None will in the future do an elementwise
>   comparison instead of just returning False. Code should be using arr
>   is None.
>
> All of these changes will give Deprecation- or FutureWarnings at this
>   time.

So far, so clear. Or is it?

We can see from @kmario23's answer that as of version 15.2 these changes are not fully implemented yet.

To make matters worse, consider this:

```
>>> A = np.array([None, a])
>>> A1 = np.array([None, a])
>>> At = np.array([None, a[:2]])
>>> 
>>> A==A1
False
>>> A==At
array([ True, False])
>>>
```

Looks like the current behavior is more a coincidence than the result of careful planning.

I suspect it all comes down to whether an exception is raised during element-wise comparison, cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50007232/7207392) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35397876/7207392).

If two corresponding elements of the containing arrays are arrays themselves and of compatible shapes as in `A==A1`, their comparison yields an array of bools. Trying to cast this to a scalar bool raises an exception. Currently, exceptions are caught and a scalar False is returned.

In the `A==At` example an exception is raised when the last two elements are compared because their shapes don't broadcast. This is caught and the comparison for this element returns a scalar False which is why comparison of the containing arrays returns a "normal" array of bools.

What about the workarounds suggested by @kmario23 and @Kanak?  Do they work?

Well, yes ...

```
>>> np.equal(A, A1, dtype=object)
array([True, array([ True,  True,  True])], dtype=object)
>>> wrpr(np.equal(A, A1, dtype=object))
True
```

... and no.

```
>>> AA = np.array([None, A])
>>> AA1 = np.array([None, A1])
>>> np.equal(AA, AA1, dtype=object)
array([True, False], dtype=object)
>>> wrpr(np.equal(AA, AA1, dtype=object))
False
```