# Two equal Keras models after set/get_weights() do not have the same weights according to numpy.array_equal()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, keras, neural-network

By using `numpy.array_equal()`, the code below shows that even after copying the weights from `model_1` to `model_2`, it still points out that both weights are different even though by looking at both weights, they are indeed equal to one another. Why?

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model_1 = Sequential([
  Dense(1, activation='relu', input_shape=(10,)),
])

model_2 = Sequential([
  Dense(1, activation='relu', input_shape=(10,)),
])

model_2.set_weights(model_1.get_weights())
print(model_1.get_weights())
print()
print(model_2.get_weights())
print()
print(np.array_equal(model_1.get_weights(), model_2.get_weights()))
```

The output I get:

```
[array([[-0.37920648],
       [-0.23108077],
       [ 0.43857104],
       [-0.58995485],
       [-0.7320645 ],
       [-0.65417486],
       [ 0.6509816 ],
       [-0.41319188],
       [ 0.54799384],
       [ 0.7301964 ]], dtype=float32), array([0.], dtype=float32)]

[array([[-0.37920648],
       [-0.23108077],
       [ 0.43857104],
       [-0.58995485],
       [-0.7320645 ],
       [-0.65417486],
       [ 0.6509816 ],
       [-0.41319188],
       [ 0.54799384],
       [ 0.7301964 ]], dtype=float32), array([0.], dtype=float32)]

False
```

Expected output: True

Comment: `np.all_close` is better for floats

Comment: @hpaulj I get the following error if I use np.allclose: `TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: Those look 2 element object dtype arrays (or lists) containing arrays with different shape.  So you can't readily compare rhem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_weights()` returns a list of numpy arrays.

When you pass lists of numpy arrays to `array_equal`, each list is internally converted to a numpy array of `object` `dtype`, which you can't simply do equality checks on.

See [here for a related question and further explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715049/comparing-numpy-array-of-dtype-object)