# Numpy Array Mask Bytes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, object, mask

I have been trying to get simple numpy masking working without having to resort to non-numpy functions, however, I have ran into what seems like a bug.

```
import numpy as np
origlist = np.array([[b'\x00'] * 100 ] * 128, dtype=np.object)
origlist[0][0] = b'\x00\x00'
newlist = origlist[0][origlist[0] != b'\x00\x00']
```

provides newlist as ***[b'\x00\00', b'\x00', b'\x00', ... ]***, where as it is supposed to provide it as ***[b'\x00', b'\x00', ... ]***.

Similarly,

```
import numpy as np
origlist = np.array([[b'\x00'] * 100 ] * 128, dtype=np.object)
origlist[0][0] = b'\x00\x00'
newlist = origlist[origlist != b'\x00']
```

also provides newlist as ***[b'\x00\00', b'\x00', b'\x00', ... ]***, where as it is supposed to provide it as ***[b'\x00\x00' ]***.

**UPDATE**

[Comparing numpy array of dtype object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715049/comparing-numpy-array-of-dtype-object)

I have tried basically everything mentioned in the post above, and nothing helped, all comparisons always evaluated to True.  I have also tried replacing the initialization with np.full instead, and same results.

The only way I was able to get it working with numpy version 1.19, is to not use numpy.

```
import numpy as np
origlist = np.full((128,100),b'\x00',dtype=object) #np.object is depreciated
origlist[0][0] = b'\x00\x00'
newlist = origlist[0].tolist()
newlist = list( filter( (b'\x00').__ne__, newlist))
```

now returns the correct ***[b'\x00\x00' ]***.

If there is any other numpy way to do this, or any numpy way to fix this, please let me know.

Comment: `[....]*4` makes 4 references to the same object, not 4 separate copies. This construction is dangerous in lists, and in object dtype arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj, this is useful information to know, and the replacement is np.full, but this didn't fix the issue.

Comment: `full` doesn't make copies either.